# List method to get difference of another list with duplicates (listobject.Expect method does not work)

Tags: c#, .net, collections

There are two Lists. I need the difference

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>() {18, 13, 22, 24, 20, 20, 27, 31, 25, 28 };
List<int> list2 = new List<int>() {18, 13, 22, 24, 20, 20, 20, 27, 31, 25, 28, 86, 78, 25 };

var listDif = list2.Except(list1);

foreach (var s in listDif)
Console.WriteLine(s);
Console.Read();
```

the answer should be 20, 86,78, 25
but it only outputs 86,78

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want exactly *that kind of behaviour* you should try this:

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>() { 18, 13, 22, 24, 20, 20, 27, 31, 25, 28 };
List<int> list2 = new List<int>() { 18, 13, 22, 24, 20, 20, 20, 27, 31, 25, 28, 86, 78, 25 };

// Remove elements of first list from second list
list1.ForEach(l => list2.Remove(l));
list2 = list2.Distinct().ToList();

list2.ForEach(d => Console.WriteLine(d));
Console.Read();
```

Comment: Thnx a lot  for the help

Comment: I am glad if I could helped @ron404

Answer (score 2):

This works fine:

1. Make a clone of `list2`
2. Remove `list1` items from `list2`

**Code Sample:**

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>() { 18, 13, 22, 24, 20, 20, 27, 31, 25, 28 };
List<int> list2 = new List<int>() { 18, 13, 22, 24, 20, 20, 20, 27, 31, 25, 28, 86, 78, 25 };

var diff = list2;
list1.All(x => diff.Remove(x));
```

You can also perform `Remove` on `list2`, however, that will modify `list2`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you only check which numbers in `list1` are missing in `list2` 
But you need to check which numbers in `list2` doesn't exist in `list1` and in 
`listDif`.
You can do

```
    List<int> diff = new List<int>();

    foreach (int num in list1)
    {
       if (!list2.Contains(num))
       {
         diff.Add(num);
       }
    }

    foreach (int num in list2)
    {
       if (!list1.Contains(num) && !diff.contains(num))
       {
          diff.Add(num);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Your code won't compile. Many syntax error's. change `add` to `Add`

Comment: @Rahul Nikate you right. this is what heppens when i'm writing too quickly :) 10xs